# "Neither" between two objects in negative sentence

Tags: objects, neither-nor

I had written sentence like this:

> However, this approach does not easily allow us to calculate confidence intervals for population growth **and** other derived quantities, since this way we do not obtain the joint distribution.

But one academic professor (non-native English speaker, but very experienced) corrected it and changed "and" to "neither":

> However, this approach does not easily allow us to calculate confidence intervals for population growth **neither** other derived quantities, since this way we do not obtain the joint distribution.

To me, it doesn't sound correct. **Can "neither" be used this way? Should there be "nor" instead? Or was my "and" the best? What is the best way to write this?**

Note: this is grammatically slightly different than the usual use for neither-nor, because here it doesn't separate sentences, but two different objects in one negative sentence. But perhaps it could still be used somehow?

Comment: Correcting awful corrections from superiors is a danger in academics. The original makes sense, and *nor* is better, but *neither* is in the wrong place.

Comment: Just change *neither* to *nor*, which works fine. That's probably what your supervisor meant, anyway.

Comment: It's not a nice sentence. I'd change *easy* for *difficult* and adjust accordingly, losing the negation.

Comment: However, this approach does not easily allow us to calculate confidence intervals for either population growth or other derived quantities, since this way we do not obtain the joint distribution.

Comment: *And* is correct. Take out the negative to see: *This approach allows us to calculate confidence intervals for population growth and other derived quantities.* Your final clause could use some help though. Try: *since it does not yield a joint distribution*. (The antecedent for *it* is *approach*.)

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat: But the difference between *and* and *or/nor* ***is*** the negative. Consider the following sentences: *(1) He likes liver **and** brussels sprouts, (2) He doesn't like liver **or** brussels sprouts*. The correct conjunction is either *or* or *nor*.

Comment: @PeterShor :  *\*He doesn't like liver nor brussels sprouts* is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence can be modified to use 'neither-nor' like this-

> However, this approach *neither* easily allows us to calculate confidence intervals for population growth *nor* does it for other derived quantities, since this way we do not obtain the joint distribution.

The academic professor's correction is wrong, since his sentence means- '..none of the other derived quantities', which isn't correct as per the context of your sentence.